# Filtering Results Using `get_context_data` in a ListView

Tags: python, django, django-views

In my ListView, I want to return the entire list of objects from my Publication model and return the **`total`** from my Budget model to include in the ListView with each title and the associated total.

**My Models:**

*Publication App*

```
class Publication(models.Model):
      title = models.CharField(...)
```

*Budget App*

```
class Budget(models.Model):
      total = models.DecimalField(...)
      publication = models.ForeignKey(Publication, ...)
```

---

**Views:** 
*Publication App*

```
class PublicationListView(ListView):
      context_object_name = 'publications'
      model = Publication

      def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
          context = super(PublicationListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

          context['publication'] = self.get_queryset()
          context['budget'] = Budget.objects.all()

          return context
```

---

**Template:** 
*Publication App*

```
<tbody>
   {% for pub in publications %}
    <tr>
        <td><a href="{{ pub.pk }}">{{ pub.title }}</a>
            <span class="float-right">
                 {% for obj in budget %}
                     {{obj}}
                 {% endfor %}
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
   {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

---

In my template, the results I am receiving look something like this:

```
publication 1               1000 2000 3000
publication 2               1000 2000 3000
publication 3               1000 2000 3000
```

But what I need is:

```
publication 1               1000
publication 2               2000
publication 3               3000
```

I understand why I am returning all budget objects in each row, but I am not sure how to only display the correct budget with the associated publication.

Is using `get_context_data()` the best option for this?

Comment: The error is with the template. Can you share the template. You should *not* iterate over the `Budget` objects, but fetch the `budget_set` of the `Publication`.

Comment: You don't need to explicitly include `budget` in the context. Related budget instances can be accessed from a `Publication` instance. `{% for budget in publication.budget_set %}`.

Comment: @HåkenLid  - Thanks for steering me in the right direction. It was, in fact, the template. Earlier I was receiving a 'RelatedManager' error then ended up down the context_data rabbit hole.  needed to call publication.budget_set.all to return the results.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks, that was the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the direction of @HakenLid and @WillemVanOnsem, below are the updated view and template to achieve the desired output

**View**

```
class PublicationListView(ListView):
      context_object_name = 'publications'
      model = Publication
```

**Template**

```
<tbody>
   {% for pub in publications %}
    <tr>
        <td><a href="{{ pub.pk }}">{{ pub.title }}</a>
            <span class="float-right">
                 {% for budget in pub.budget_set.all %}
                     {{ budget }}
                 {% endfor %}
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
   {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```